# missing node.socket

Tags: cardano-node, cabal

so I synced towards Alonzo mainnet with [cabal build](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-node) and interrupted at 92% and somehow `~/cardano/db/node.socket` is missing. And no matter how many times I restart the node with

```
cardano-node run \
--config /home/user/cardano/mainnet-config.json \
--database-path /home/user/cardano/db/ \
--socket-path /home/user/cardano/db/node.socket \
--host-addr 127.0.0.1 \
--port 3001 \
--topology /home/user/cardano/mainnet-topology.json
```

it gets stuck at

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:12798
[hud-PS63:cardano.node.networkMagic:Notice:5] [2021-09-16 02:17:41.27 UTC] NetworkMagic 764824073
[hud-PS63:cardano.node.basicInfo.protocol:Notice:5] [2021-09-16 02:17:41.27 UTC] Byron; Shelley
[hud-PS63:cardano.node.basicInfo.version:Notice:5] [2021-09-16 02:17:41.27 UTC] 1.29.0
[hud-PS63:cardano.node.basicInfo.commit:Notice:5] [2021-09-16 02:17:41.27 UTC] 48429531f0d3d71fadce9a5971bf56a6df396f2d
[hud-PS63:cardano.node.basicInfo.nodeStartTime:Notice:5] [2021-09-16 02:17:41.27 UTC] 2021-09-16 02:17:41.275947702 UTC
[hud-PS63:cardano.node.basicInfo.systemStartTime:Notice:5] [2021-09-16 02:17:41.27 UTC] 2017-09-23 21:44:51 UTC
[hud-PS63:cardano.node.basicInfo.slotLengthByron:Notice:5] [2021-09-16 02:17:41.27 UTC] 20s
[hud-PS63:cardano.node.basicInfo.epochLengthByron:Notice:5] [2021-09-16 02:17:41.27 UTC] 21600
[hud-PS63:cardano.node.basicInfo.slotLengthShelley:Notice:5] [2021-09-16 02:17:41.27 UTC] 1s
[hud-PS63:cardano.node.basicInfo.epochLengthShelley:Notice:5] [2021-09-16 02:17:41.27 UTC] 432000
[hud-PS63:cardano.node.basicInfo.slotsPerKESPeriodShelley:Notice:5] [2021-09-16 02:17:41.27 UTC] 129600
[hud-PS63:cardano.node.basicInfo.slotLengthAllegra:Notice:5] [2021-09-16 02:17:41.27 UTC] 1s
[hud-PS63:cardano.node.basicInfo.epochLengthAllegra:Notice:5] [2021-09-16 02:17:41.27 UTC] 432000
[hud-PS63:cardano.node.basicInfo.slotsPerKESPeriodAllegra:Notice:5] [2021-09-16 02:17:41.27 UTC] 129600
[hud-PS63:cardano.node.basicInfo.slotLengthMary:Notice:5] [2021-09-16 02:17:41.27 UTC] 1s
[hud-PS63:cardano.node.basicInfo.epochLengthMary:Notice:5] [2021-09-16 02:17:41.27 UTC] 432000
[hud-PS63:cardano.node.basicInfo.slotsPerKESPeriodMary:Notice:5] [2021-09-16 02:17:41.27 UTC] 129600
[hud-PS63:cardano.node.basicInfo.slotLengthAlonzo:Notice:5] [2021-09-16 02:17:41.27 UTC] 1s
[hud-PS63:cardano.node.basicInfo.epochLengthAlonzo:Notice:5] [2021-09-16 02:17:41.27 UTC] 432000
[hud-PS63:cardano.node.basicInfo.slotsPerKESPeriodAlonzo:Notice:5] [2021-09-16 02:17:41.27 UTC] 129600
[hud-PS63:cardano.node.addresses:Notice:5] [2021-09-16 02:17:41.27 UTC] [SocketInfo 0.0.0.0:3001]
[hud-PS63:cardano.node.diffusion-mode:Notice:5] [2021-09-16 02:17:41.27 UTC] InitiatorAndResponderDiffusionMode
[hud-PS63:cardano.node.dns-producers:Notice:5] [2021-09-16 02:17:41.27 UTC] [DnsSubscriptionTarget {dstDomain = "relays-new.cardano-mainnet.iohk.io", dstPort = 3001, dstValency = 2}]
[hud-PS63:cardano.node.ip-producers:Notice:5] [2021-09-16 02:17:41.27 UTC] IPSubscriptionTarget {ispIps = [], ispValency = 0}
```

Is there a log to check what happened during the interruption? where is this stored (following cabal build documentation)

Comment: Please check if there is enough disk space. Node.socket will be created only when the node is running

Comment: used about 117gb and 17 gb left. I reran, synced to >91% (database at 14 Gb), stopped the sync - checked and`node.socket=` still in db folder, once I rerun `cardano-node run ...` `node.socket=` is gone.

is 17gb too little?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this stage, it is normal that your node.socket does not yet exist because your launch has not passed the step ***IPSubscriptionTarget {ispIps = [], ispValency = 0}***. It usually happens because your cardano-node has not been gracefully stopped.

If it continues from there after 30 min or so (assuming that you have a decent CPU with enough memory) it would be a sign of a hard shutdown. We sometimes have the impression that the program has frozen but it is because your cardano-node needs to scan and verify all the data again so it can take a while.

When you see a line like

```
Opened vol db
```

your node.socket will be here again.

Comment: Yes there has been some issues where my PC shuts down unexpectedly. But waiting for the node.socket to reappear just needs time!

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting the CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH again. An exported variable will only remain alive while the user who issued the command is active in their session. You can add this also to a startup script in that user's space.